# WPF Tabs Stack button

Tags: wpf, animation, button

I have 5 buttons stacked as below, with each button corresponding to a grid containing datagrid. Now I click on the 2nd button below, I want the second button to move up grid.row="1" with its grid part to move up Grid.Row="2" and its Grid.SpanRow = "5" (the first button remains in place but its grid will disapear) and it must have an up animation. but I can't know how to do this and how to hide grids when another grid is showing. Anyone have any other ideas for me? Sorry for my bad discription cuz i just started coding with wpf 2 weaks ago. Thanks all guys first.
This is my code:

```
<Border>
    <Grid>

             <Grid.RowDefinitions> 
                ...*11Rows (I dont know why this isn't shown, Grid.RowDefinitions)
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Button > Phương tiện</Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="7" Name="btn1"> Điểm đánh dấu
            
            </Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="8">Cây tốc độ</Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="9">Tìm kiếm nhanh</Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="10">Mô phỏng lịch sử</Button>
            <Button Grid.Row="11">Điểm đánh dấu</Button>
            
            
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="6" x:Name="gr1"> blabla </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
```

[image]

[[image: Like this after clicking the second button][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNsLx.png)

Comment: You should use a `ListBox`. Then create a class for each item type which holds the relevant data. Create a model class that exposes a `ObservableCollection` of those data classes wto which the `ListBox.ItemsSource` can bind to. Then create a nameless `DataTemplate` for each of your data classes and put them in the resource dictionary of _App.xaml_.

Comment: To design the items use a header and the `Expander` control to expand additional content for each item header. This way you eliminate the `Grid` with its loads of rows. Bind the `ListBox.Selected` item to the model class that exposes the items. This selected item is part of the item source collection. Just move this selected item up e.g. to index 1 inside this collection. The view will automatically update itself to reposition the selected item

Comment: You need: [Data binding overview in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview), [Data templating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview#data-templating), [Expander Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/expander-overview).